# Java button's appearance style during holding down

Tags: java, swing, button

```
// plain green button
flatButton.setBorderPainted (false);
flatButton.setBackground (Color.green);
flatButton.setSize (100, 75);
```

While holding the button, its color change to blue.
How to make keep green color during holding down?

Comment: A little more context (type of flatButton, who calls and when start/stopButton) might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
flatButton.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```